# What is the difference between a token and a digest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm learning about authenticating users in rails and the concept of tokens and digests keep reappearing. I think I understand the general idea of what their purposes are in general, but I don't understand the difference between the two.

Answer (score 6):

- Token is just a random string
- Digest is a hashed string

*A cryptographic hash function is a procedure that takes data and return a fixed bit string: the hash value, also known as digest. Hash functions are also called one-way functions, it is easy to compute a digest from a message, but it is infeasible to generate a message from a digest.*

Read more about digest here: http://apidock.com/ruby/Digest

Comment: Another way of looking at it is a digest is like a random string or value that can be reproduced on demand based on a given input, but a token can be totally random and doesn't necessarily need to be reproducible.